# How to access values of multiple parameters passed to Laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel-4, parameter-passing

I am trying to figure out how to access two (or more) parameters passed to a Laravel controller. I know how to create the route, and the URL is created correctly, but then I can only access the first passed parameter in my controller.

Route:

```
Route::get('managers/{id}/{parameter2}', array('as'=>'dosomething', 'uses'=> 'ManagersController@dosomething'));
```

where the first parameter is obviously the $id for managers, and the second parameters is to be processed by the controller.

View:

```
<a href="{{ URL::route('do something',array($manager->id,'parameter2') }}" class="styleClass">Do Something</a>
```

generates the URL:

```
http://domain/managers/1/2
```

where 1 is easily accessed as the $id for managers, but when I try to access the 2nd parameter "2" using $parameter2, e.g. using a simple return: "id=$id and parameter2=$parameter2" statement, I get an "unidentified variable: $parameter2" error.

What am I doing wrong?

Is there a better way to pass multiple parameters? I'm especially asking the "better way?" question because what I want to do is use the 2nd parameter to change a value in a database table, and using a 'get' method, somebody could change the parameter value in the URL and therefore cause mischief. Must I use a 'post' method? I'd love to be able to use a link, since that works much better with the design of my application.

Thanks!

---

I was asked to include the controller, which I'm happy to do. Initially, just for testing, as I mentioned, my controller was a simple return to display the values of the two passed parameters. But here is what I want to be able to do, including the actual name of the function ("update_group" rather than "dosomething") --

ManagersController:

```
public function update_group($id)
{
    DB::table('groups')->where('id','=',$parameter2)->update(array('manager_id'=>$id));
    return Redirect::route('managers.show', array('id'=>$id));
}
```

The update table works perfectly if I replace $parameter2 with an actual value, so that syntax is fine. The issue is that Laravel says that $parameter2 is an undefined variable, despite the fact that the URL contains the value of $parameter2 as you can see above.

And since it occurs to me that the answer to this may involve adding a function to the Manager model, here is the current

Manager.php

```
class Manager extends Eloquent {

protected $table = 'managers'; ... (mutator and error functions)

}
```

Comment: Post your controller `dosomething` function

Comment: I've added the controller, and the model. See above. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change

```
public function update_group($id)
```

to

```
public function update_group($id, $parameter2)
```

Comment: Thank you! Of course! (Silly me!) I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

All looks ok in your route.  Seeing the controller code would help, but likely, you may not have a second parameter in your controller's dosomething() method.

```
public function dosomething($id, $parameter2){
    var_dump($id).'<br />';
    var_dump($paremter2);
}
```

If that isn't the case, you can try dumping it from the route's callback to further diagnose.

```
Route::get('managers/{id}/{parameter2}', function($id, $parameter2)
{
    var_dump($id).'<br />';
    var_dump($paremter2);
});
```

Depending on your use case, you can pass them in a query string like so: but it isn't really the 'best way', unless you're doing something like building an API that won't use the same variables in the same order all the time.

```
/managers?id=1&paramter2=secondParameter

var_dump(Request::query('id')).'<br />';
var_dump(Request::query('paramter2'));
```

Comment: Thanks. I've added the controller to my original question above. The var_dump gives the same result as a return that attempts to display the parameter values -- each time, I get an "Undefined variable: parameter2" error. I get the same error if I try to use a query string. The Route is back to the controller, so that doesn't help. As I mentioned, the URL is constructed correctly, it's just that I'm unable to access the 2nd parameter within the controller. There must be a way to do that.

Comment: you're route is passing $parameter2, but your controller isn't accepting it.  Try changing your method declaration to `public function update_group($id, $parameter2)`  That should do the trick.